# How do you create dropdown boxes for forms in django?

Tags: python, django, web

I was trying to create a dropdown box in django but there is very little helpful documentation. I know it has something to do with ChoiceFields but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone post an example that I could work off?

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works. You need to post the code you tried and the errors you got.

Comment: oh sorry stackoverflow expert

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the formfield Choicefield (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/), but an easier way is to define the choices in your model.py file.

For example:

```
listofchoices = models.CharField(
    max_length=30,
    choices= (
    ('choice1', 'Choice 1'),
    ('choice2', 'Choice 2'),
    ('choice3', 'Choice 3'),
    ('choice4', 'Choice 4'),
    ),
    default='choice1',
    )
```

In your forms.py file you can then treat it just like any other charField, e.g.:

```
class GiveChoicesForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = ModelName 
    fields = ('listofchoices', 'otherfield1', 'otherfield2')
```

Django will then create a dropdown box including the given choices